# Does the inequality $\inf_{|z|=1} U(x, z)\le U(x, y/|y|)\le \sup_{|z|=1} U(x, z)$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $U\in C^1(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$.

During class, the lecturer stated that it is possible to find two functions $a_1, a_2:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$ U(x, y/|y|)\ge \inf_{|z|=1} U(x, z)\ge a_1(x)$$
and
$$ U(x, y/|y|)\le \sup_{|z|=1} U(x, z)\le a_2(x).$$

Anyone could please help me to understand why is that true?
I do not even understand why he wrote that
$$\inf_{|z|=1} U(x, z)\le U(x, y/|y|)\le \sup_{|z|=1} U(x, z).$$

Thank you in advance.